# Mono with SQL Server Membership Provider?

Tags: asp.net, mono, asp.net-membership

Apparently Mono replaces references to SQL Server membership provider with sqlite membership provider (see [ASP.NET_Settings_Mapping](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET_Settings_Mapping)). Is there any way to convince Mono to use SQL Server for the membership provider?

When I try to log in to my web app, I get the following:

```
System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: Operation aborted due to an exception (see Trace for details).
at System.Web.Security.SqliteMembershipProvider.ValidateUser (string,string) <0x003bb>
at DirectMail.Controllers.AccountMembershipService.ValidateUser (string,string) [0x00000] in [file].cs:404
at DirectMail.Controllers.AccountController.ValidateLogOn (string,string) [0x00040] in [file].cs:346
at DirectMail.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn (string,string,bool,string) [0x00000] in [file].cs:79
at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExecutionScope.lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExecutionScope,System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase,object[]) <0x001c1>
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase,object[]) <0x00028>
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<string, object>) <0x0015b>
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext,System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<string, object>) <0x00036>
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker/<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>c__AnonStoreyB.<>m__E () <0x00092>
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter (System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter,System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext,System.Func`1<System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext>) <0x00125>
```

---

The top of the file `/usr/local/etc/mono/4.0/settings.map` on one Debian Linux machine is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<settingsMap>
  <map sectionType="System.Web.Configuration.MembershipSection, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       mapperType="Mono.Web.Util.MembershipSectionMapper, Mono.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756"
       platform="Unix">

    <!-- The 'what' tag specifies which region of the section to modify. The 'value' attribute value is mapper-specific and is not defined here. It can be
         any expression understood by the mapper to designate the section region to modify.
    -->
    <what value="providers">
      <!-- 'what' can contain any number of occurrences of any three elements:
              replace - replace the designated region
        add - add a new entry to the region
        clear - clear the region
        remove - remove the designatedregion

              The attributes to any of the above are freeform and are not processed by the mapper manager. They are stored verbatim for the
        mapper to peruse.
      -->
      <replace name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqliteMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         connectionStringName="LocalSqliteServer" />
    </what>
  </map>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: On the page [ASP.NET Settings Mapping](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET_Settings_Mapping) that you linked to, in the section titled "Inhibiting the settings mapping", it says that adding `<add key="MonoAspnetInhibitSettingsMap" value="anything"/>` to the `appSettings` element in the app's `Web.config` will inhibit the settings map. I found, however, that value "anything" does not work. If I use the value "true", then it does.

Comment: This looks like it may possibly work. Could you add this as an answer so I can mark it correct if it does work?

Comment: I converted the comment to an answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846487/mono-with-sql-server-membership-provider/4853323#4853323](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846487/mono-with-sql-server-membership-provider/4853323#4853323)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the [ASP.NET Settings Mapping](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET_Settings_Mapping) page that you linked to, in the section titled "Inhibiting the settings mapping", it says that adding:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="MonoAspnetInhibitSettingsMap" value="anything"/>
</appSettings>
```

to your app's `Web.config` file will disable settings mapping. I found, however, that value "anything" does not work. If I use the value "true" instead, then it does:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="MonoAspnetInhibitSettingsMap" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

This must be a misconfiguration because an implemented sqlmembershipprovider exists for Mono 2.0. It is using a DBProviderFactory to obtain a connection. A SqlClient implementation is also there so that only leads to the conclusion that the web.config for the website is not correct, which is not unthinkable because sqlclient and sqlite almost looks the same in an overcrowded web.config.

If anyone can post that one, that might clarify the problem at hand.

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC 2 project that I am working on which uses `SqlMembershipProvider` was generated on Windows with Visual Web Developer 2010. I ran the project by clicking on the "Debug" icon in VWD and verified that the SQL Server database was being accessed. I copied the sources onto a Debian Linux machine and then tried running the web app with `xsp4`. It basically worked, but an error occurred when attempting to use the membership provider features.

Comment: Your answer prompted me to revisit the system configuration files, and I noticed something suspicious in `/usr/local/etc/mono/4.0/settings.map` (Mono on the Debian Linux machine was compiled from source). I will add the relevant parts to the question.

Comment: I Still feel that you should reference the SQLProvider from mono. I have no debian host with mono now but if you replace SqliteMembershipProvider with SqlMembershipProvider  in your config and sqliteconnection with sqlconnection you should be in business.

Comment: rene, I will post the web.config later, but I can guarantee you it does not reference sqlite. The web.config was generated with VS 2008 and works great in production with SQL Server. For now, there were so many issues getting it running with Mono I've given up, but for the benefit of the community I will post my configuration.